# Intellij module groups disappearing after importing project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

As the title indicates, my module groups all disappear after I import a new maven project.

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139882

Comment: that's exactly it, cant you please post it as an answer so that I can accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when `Create module-groups for multi-module Maven projects` option is enabled. See the [related request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139882). Disabling this option should help:

[image: groups]